# How can I display decoded str or unicode in VSCode console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to debug my app. In debug panel, variables with Latin characters are displayed correctly, but encoded string like Chinese are not decoded as expected.

```
s = "测试"
```

and the debug panel and console output(not print) is

```
s: '\xe6\xb5\x8b\xe8\xaf\x95'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Could you use python3? For me, this doesn't occur when using python3 as the python interpreter (python2 does not handle unicode as well).